# Filtering elements when selecting objects with children()

Tags: angularjs

In this [PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/0BUBoMprI9ClO25lKQKr?p=preview) I have a directive that appends to the element a div with three children. Two children are divs and a third child is a span.

I need to loop through the children, but discarding anything that is not a div.

I tried

```
var children = wrap.children().find( "div" );
```

but it doesn't return anything. This works but retuns also the span

```
var children = wrap.children();
```

How to make this work?

Javascript

```
    directive.link = function (scope, element, attrs) {

       var wrap = angular.element('<div id="wrap"></div>');
       var wrapc = $compile(wrap)(scope)
       element.append(wrapc); 

       var node1 = angular.element('<div id="node1"></div>');
       var node1c = $compile(node1)(scope)
       wrapc.append(node1c);

       var node2 = angular.element('<div id="node2"></div>');
       var node2c = $compile(node2)(scope)
       wrapc.append(node2c);

       var span1 = angular.element('<span id="span1">text</span>');
       var span1c = $compile(span1)(scope)
       wrapc.append(span1c);

        // var children = wrap.children().find( "div" );
        var children = wrap.children();
        angular.forEach(children, function(value, key){
            console.log(value);
        });
    };
```

Comment: What is the final HTML structure you are looking for?

Comment: this is just a snippet, I need to filter the divs only. The structure is one div (wrap) with three children